# How use Codeigniter instance in abstract class?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I created a standart class `Loadercontent`(controller) in Codeigniter.
Also in the same file a add `abstract Search` class and child class `SearchDoctor`:

When I try to get CI instance `&get_instance();` at abstract constructor, I get NULL:

```
$this->_ci =&get_instance();
var_dump($this->_ci); // NULL
```

So after I can not use:

```
$this->_ci->load->view($this->view, $this->item);
```

because `$this->_ci` is empty. What is wrong in my code ot abstract class in CI? Also maybe you can ask something about code? Is it wrong?

The full code:

```
<?php

abstract class Search
{
    protected $fields = array('country' => 'country', 'city' => 'city');
    protected $table;
    protected $limit = 20;
    protected $offset = 0;
    protected $items;
    protected $rand = false;
    protected $data;
    protected $view;
    protected $_ci;

    public function __construct($input)
    {
        $this->_ci =&get_instance();
        $this->data = $input;
        $this->getPostGet();
    }

    public function getPostGet(){
        if(empty($this->data)){
            foreach($this->data as $key => $val){
                $this->_check($val, $key);
            }
        }
    }

    public function _check($val, $key){
        if(in_array($val, $this->fields)){
            $this->items[] = $this->getField($val, $key);
        }
    }

    public function getField($value, $key){
        return $key. ' = '.$value;
    }

    public function doQuery(){
        if(!empty($this->items)){
            $limit = $this->formatLimit();
            $this->items = $this->other_model->getItemsTable($this->query, $this->table, $limit);
        }
    }

    public function formatLimit(){
        $this->offset = (isset($this->data['limit'])) ? $this->data['limit'] : $this->offset;
        $this->limit  = (isset($this->data['limit'])) ? $this->offset + $this->limit : $this->limit;
        return array('offset' => $this->limit, 'limit' => $this->limit);
    }

    public function addFields($array){
        $this->fields = array_merge($this->fields, $array);
    }

    public function getView(){
        $this->_ci->load->view($this->view, $this->item);
    }

    public function response(){
        echo json_encode($this->view); die();
    }
}


class SearchDoctor extends Search
{
    protected $fields = array('name' => 'DetailToUsersName');

    public function __construct($type)
    {
        $this->table  = 'users';
        $this->view   = 'users/doctors_list';
        $this->limit  = 10;
        $this->rand   = true;

        $this->addFields($this->fields);
        parent::__construct($type);
    }
}

/* Init class */

class Loadercontent {

    public function index(){
        if(isset($_GET) || isset($_POST)){

            $class = 'Search';

            if(isset($_POST['type'])){
                $type   = $_POST['type'];
                $input  = $_POST;
            }

            if(isset($_GET['type'])){
                $type   = $_GET['type'];
                $input  = $_GET;
            }

            $class = $class.$type;

            if (class_exists($class)) {
                $obj = new $class($input);
                $obj->getView();
                $obj->response();
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Hi, i just tested your code with some simplifications, i only used the variable $_ci and i called the method getView, and it worked perfectely for me!!, but if you still been stuck with this problem, why dont you just pass the context to the class constructor `new $class($input,$this)`

Comment: Thanks a lot, will check again. What can you say about clear class? Is it good work or need to change something? May be use singleton pattern? The goal is to create pagination for different content.

Comment: It can not work because `Loadercontent` is not extended by `CI_Controller`

Comment: ooh! i didn't pay attention to that(sorry my bad), if `get_instance()` returns null it means that CI instance is not loaded yet! are your trying to create some kind of [library](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html) if so, check the doc and be sure you respect their specifications